# Formatting csv row made from dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am writing appending new dictionary entries to a csv as they are made. This works completely fine, however the formatting is funky. I am recording the trades my automated strategy makes. It records the timestamp, the trade, and the price.

Here is my function that records a new dictionary entry and appends to my csv:

```
def record_example(x):
    now = datetime.now()
    unix = int(mktime(now.timetuple()))
    price = 8110

    log.example[unix] = [unix, x, price]

    with open('example.csv', 'a') as e:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(e, fieldnames=log.example)
        writer.writerow(log.example)

        e.close()
```

I call the function w/:

```
record('buy')
```

this creates the dictionary as it should:

```
{1559052353: [1559052353, 'buy', 8110]}
```

however the entry into the csv now looks like with it only filling A1:

```
"[1559052353, 'buy', 8110]"
```

when I am trying to get it to look like: (so that I can import the csv into another .py file and plot trade performance)

```
1559052353, buy, 8110
```

so that 1559052353 will be in A1, buy in A2, and 8110 in A3 for example

I have tried ''.join(split(',') for each row in csv yet get error message.. thanks so much if you can help!

Comment: you don't need to use `e.close()`. the with block closes the file automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your code you get header to be `1559052353` and the value is the whole list (converted to str, that's why you get also the double quotes)

I believe you want to have fieldnames `unix,x,price` and values `1559052353,buy,8110`

```
with open('example.csv', 'a') as e:
    header = ['unix', 'x', 'price']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(e, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(dict(zip(header, log.example[unix])))
```

note when using `with` context manager you don't need to call `e.close()`
you may want to make `log.example[unix]` to be a dict, not list.
also, maybe replace x in header with something else

Answer (score 0):

Check out the dialects option in [`csv.dictwriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) this allows you to set different conventions for your csv, my guess is you want `QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

Also, you're writing out a key, and a list to your dictwriter. Normally, the dictwriter will take a dictionary per row, with each field being lodged in the dictionary as a "fieldname":fieldvalue pair.

Try converting your output routine so it passes individual row-dictionaries like:

```
log.example[unix] = {"unix":unix, "x":x, "price":price}

{"unix" : 1559052353, "x" : 'buy', "price" : 8110}
```

The dictwriter will output a row with the 3 fields, "unix", "x", "price" according to your preferred csv dialect.

As it stands, you're giving it a key'ed list, so it's outputting that list "raw", which means it applies those unwanted extra decorations "[", "]"

Answer (score 0):

you probably wanted to write: `writer.writerow(log.example[unix])`. this will do the thing you want. you also don't need to use `e.close()`, as the `with` block closes the file automatically for you.